# PHP Database check doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I somewhat have a weird problem. I'm trying to check if a certain value exists in a database via a self created function, like this

```
function is_in_db($val,$row,$db){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT ".$row." FROM ".$db." WHERE ".$row." = '".$val."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

As far as i know this works (i checked it outside the function and echo'd the results. It works fine there. But when i do this, it keps constantly displaying 'yes' (where it should display 'no')

```
    if(is_in_db($_aGET,"c_link","fe_content")){
        echo("yes");
    }else{
        echo("no");
    }
```

All the variables work and are correctly, i checked that!

Does anybody know what i do wrong here?

---

**Edit:**
Here is some additional information. My database looks (simplified) like this:

```
Database: fe_content
+--------+--------+
| c_link | c_page |
+--------+--------+
|  one   | page 1 |
|  two   | page 2 |
| three  | page 3 |
+-----------------+
```

I have the following url `www.domain.com/page/two`

In page.php i have the following (relevant only) code:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])){
    $_aGET = substr($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1);
    $_aGET = explode('/', $_aGET);
}

function is_in_table ($val, $col, $table) {
    return (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `$col` FROM `$table` WHERE `$col` = '$val' LIMIT 1")) > 0);
}

if(empty($_aGET[0])){
    echo("Were on page.php");
}else{
    if(is_in_table($_aGET,"c_link","fe_content")){
        echo("yes");
    }else{
        echo("no");
    }
}
```

And this somehow won't work..

---

**SOLVED!**

Aahh!!!

I now see that i used `$_aGET` in stead of `$_aGET[0]` Ahh!

Sorry and thanks for helping all!!!!!!

Comment: Does `mysql_num_rows` return desired values?

Comment: *Please* change all instances of `db` to `table` so you don't get yourself confused. `db !== table`

Comment: you got some serious variable naming problems, I think instead of `$row` you should use `$column`, and instead of `$db` use `$table` to make your code more readable.

Comment: and also you might simply use `return (boolean) mysql_num_rows($query);` instead of that `if`.

Comment: You guys are right about the namegiving, wished it solved the problem ;)

Comment: And `$result` not `$query`. And please learn Markdown formatting instead of using HTML (you've been here 11 months!). And please write your solution in an _answer_, not in the question (obviously not the proper place for it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to answer your question without knowing more about your db and your variables, but I'll give it a go.

```
// A made up table called 'users'
+-------+---------+
| id    | name    |
+-------+---------+
| 1     | Bob     |
+-------+---------+
| 2     | John    |
+-------+---------+

// And here's your function
function rowExists($value, $field, $table){
    $sanitized = is_numeric($value) ? $value : "'" . $value . "'";
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT " . $field . " FROM " . $table . " WHERE " . $field . " = " . $sanitized);

    // Credit: @Omeid Herat
    return (boolean) mysql_num_rows($query);
}

// Some usage examples
rowExists('Bob', 'name', 'users'); // true
rowExists('Dave', 'name', 'users'); // false
```

This *should work*, but it is definitely not safe from SQL injections.

### Updated

```
$page = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if(empty($page[1])){
    echo "Were on page.php";
}else{
    if(is_in_table($page[1], "c_link", "fe_content")){
        echo "yes";
    }else{
        echo "no";
    }
}
```

Comment: I editted my original post with additional information on my situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While I can't actually see any mechanical problem with this code, use the version of the function below, and if yu

Change your function to this:

```
function is_in_table ($val, $col, $table) {
  return (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `$col` FROM `$table` WHERE `$col` = '$val' LIMIT 1")) > 0);
}
```

...and we'll take if from there.

Comment: Still, this doesn't work.. Ik keeps saying 'no' while i'm sure the value exists in the datase. Don't get it what's going wrong here.

Comment: What are the values you are checking for? Could it be a case-sensitivity problem? Any leading/trailing white-space either in the value in your script or the value in the DB?